# How do I confirm all elements in a hash are defined?

Tags: ruby, hash

What is the best way to check if all the objects in the Ruby hash are defined (not nil)?

The statement should return false if at least one element in the hash is nil.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use `all?` to check whether a given predicate is true for all elements in an enumerable. So:

```
hash.values.all? {|x| !x.nil?}
```

Or

```
hash.all? {|k,v| !v.nil?}
```

If you also want to check, all the keys are non-nil as well, you can amend that to:

```
hash.all? {|k,v| !v.nil? && !k.nil?}
```

Comment: Without a block `all?` automatically checks if the (array) elements are non-nil, so the value check can be reduced to `hash.values.all?`, and the keys+values check to `hash.flatten.all?`!

Comment: @glenn: Not quite. It checks that they're truthy. `false` is not `nil`, but it's also not truthy.

Comment: If you're on ruby 1.8.7 or later, or on Rails, you could do `! hash.values.any?(&:nil?)` .

Answer (score 12):

Another way:

```
!hash.values.include? nil
```

Comment: BTW, in Rails it's even better: `hash.values.exclude? nil`

Answer (score 2):

`Enumerable#all?` method does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

An element (value) that is `nil` is defined. It's defined as the `nil` object.

If you're wanting to check if there's any keys missing, then do the following:

```
hash = {:key1 => nil, :key2 => 42, :key3 => false}
keys = [:key1, :key2, :key3]
all_defined = keys.all?{|key| hash.has_key?(key)} # Returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hash = { foo: nil, bar: nil, baz: nil }
hash.values.all?(nil) # true
!hash.values.all?(nil) # false


hash = { foo: 0, bar: nil, baz: nil }
hash.values.all?(nil) # false
!hash.values.all?(nil) # true
```